# Setting page has no effect

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and my DataTables initialization code is shown below:

```js
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable({
    "paging": true,
    "columnDefs": [
    {
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        switch(parseInt(data))
        {
          case 1 : return 'Aktív';
          case 0 : return 'Inaktív';
        }
      },
      "targets": 3
    },
    {
      'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [4]
    },
    {
      'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [5]
    }]
  });
```

The problem is that when I change something in the table the last line won't work, it always returns to first page.

```js
var pageNow = $('#admin_users_table').DataTable().page();
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable().cell($(_this).parent().prev().prev()).data(which).draw();
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable().page(pageNow);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to achieve.. Also, good if you post some fiddle with this..

Comment: [$('#admin_users_table').DataTable().page(pageNow).draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())

Answer (score 1):

As [@davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345495/setting-page-has-no-effect#comment54488136_33345495) correctly mentioned, you need to call [`draw()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29) API method after setting the page as shown below:

```
$('#admin_users_table').DataTable().page(pageNow).draw();
```

See [`page()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29) API method for explanation:

> Please be aware that this method sets the page to be shown - it does not actually perform the re-display of the table. In order to have the newly set page shown use the `draw()` method, which can be called simply as a chained method of the `page()` method's returned object.